# Changing the list: A variable assigned to does not change the "id" of the variable for subsequent changes

Tags: python

Is this as expected? I thought in Python, variables are pointers to objects in memory. If I modify the python list that a variable points to once, the memory reference changes. But if I modify it again, the memory reference is the same?

```
>>> id(mylist)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mylist' is not defined
>>> mylist = [0]
>>> id(mylist)
4417893152
>>> mylist = [0, 1]
>>> id(mylist)
4418202992 # ID changes
>>> mylist.append(3)
>>> mylist
[0, 1, 3]
>>> id(mylist)
4418202992 # ID stays the same
>>> mylist.append(4)
>>> mylist
[0, 1, 3, 4]
>>> id(mylist)
4418202992 # ID stays the same
>>>
```

Comment: cannot reproduce.

Comment: I can't reproduce on my machine, so I think this is the result of the interpreter taking shortcuts (either reusing the same block of memory since it happens to be already initialized to the correct thing and it would be garbage collected anyway) or the garbage collector removing the old reference in the middle of the assignment.

Comment: The id in CPython is memory address based and when you overwrite a reference why not use the same memory for optimization? Can be different on other machines, OS or on Wednesday evening with full moon.

Comment: Looks like this is excepted behavior. From python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id): `Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.`.

Comment: I can reproduce on my machine, this is simply a compiler optimization. For me, re-assigning a variable to its initialization value changes the id of the variable, but assigning it to its initialization value with some items appended does not. This suggests that the compiler reuses the same memory address and simply writes to the memory after.

Comment: In the examples you added you **change** the list, the of cause id will keep the same then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct in that the memory references should change. Take a careful look at the memory addresses: they're not identical.

Edit: Regarding your edit, the memory address only changes on reassignment of the variable. The memory of the variable stays the same if you mutate the list.

Comment: Thanks, yep, you're right. And also, I tested it again. The memory reference seems to change "sometimes." I will update the original question with my new results.

Answer (score 2):

The memory addresses are not identical. It is behaving as expected -

`mylist = ['123']` --> Points to memory address **4338643744** (See 8643 in between)

[image]

`mylist = ['123','a']` --> Points to memory address **4338953744**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look of the id's you provided . There are completely different. 4338643744 != 4338953744. Look the first 5 numbers: 43386 != 43389. Everything is working as expects due to memory reference is changing properly.

Comment: This is a bit misleading since the memory address does not have to change according to the docs (see the comment above).

Answer (score 0):

For a mutable object, the `id` which is a `unique identifier for the specified object` will be based on the value itself.

[image]refere[image]